# Convert ball-stick model to STL from the command line

Tags: 3d

I regularly have 3D models that consist of a Boolean union of balls and cylinders (molecule models, star maps, mathematical designs), that I then want to convert to a STL model for printing at Shapeways.  But I don't know how to easily do that!  I already have the model as a series of floating point numbers (four for each ball, and seven for each cylinder), so I *don't* want to have to go into a graphical interface to click/drag points.  Instead I want to convert my lists of floating point numbers to STL from the command line.

I thought this would be a trivial thing, but I cannot find what is the best tool for this.  All I need, I think, is a pointer to what tools are most appropriate (although more detailed help will be appreciated :-))  I thought that "gmsh" might be good for this, but it is not immediately clear to me how to use it for that.

I would like the software for this to be "free", in the sense that it does not cost money.  Also, I am not a Windows user, so I would like to be able to run this under Linux or macOS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about 3D modeling for 3D printing. Try 3D printing stackexhange.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't pay attention and posted to the wrong forum. I now reposted on the 3D printing stackexchange, although the answer here already satisfies all my needs. But I wondered whether the people there would come up with some alternatives (thus far they didn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that this question is better suited to the 3D stack exchange. Perhaps a moderator will migrate it, hence this answer.

To the OP:

You may consider to use the free program [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/) which works with Linux and can be run via command line. For your purposes, you may find it more useful to run it in GUI mode as it is a text based description type of program. Your values can be entered into the editor with appropriate modifiers to create the objects you require.

[image: openscad screen shot]

There is a [thingiverse entry](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1129007) which provides for someone else's creation of various molecules, using OpenSCAD. The files accompanying the entry include the OpenSCAD code, which you'd be able to use as a reference or to modify to meet your requirements, reducing the learning curve.

[image: thingiverse sample molecule]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed, thanks!